# Delete every line with a specific numbered character - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find questions that resolve mine.

I would like to delete every line of a notepad document that has the number "3" as its 10th character. How would I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Want you remove the whole line with the new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

press `CTRL + H`

put `^.{9}3.*\r?\n?` into `Find what:` field.

put nothing in `replace with:` field.

then press `ALT + A`.

It will remove every line which has `3` as the 10th character with the new line at the end of the line.

don't check `matches newline` option.